# Should I use “withdrawal” or “exchange,” when spending credit card points?

Tags: word-choice

I wonder that which word is used when spending credit card points, *withdrawal* or *exchange*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, the term you hear in this case is **"Redeem"**

Like these:

[image: Credit Card Ad:]

[image: Credit Card Ad 2]

Comment: Thank you your detailed answer. In that case `redemption` is supposed to be a word which is used to specify this action. Is it corect?

Comment: @efkan "Redemption" would be the noun form of "to redeem". Does that answer your question?

Comment: No, it does not. Your answer is what I asked for. It is ok and i have accepted it. Actually redemption is what I looked for :)